# Are there resources about logistics?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, scheduling, logistics

I couldn't find any complex resources in Google.  Maybe the key words that I used were wrong.

I am interested in web-sites, book titles, book authors etc..
I'm looking general theory.

UPD:
Previous title of the question was: "Are there resources about transport scheduling?".

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? Are you looking at a specific problem, or looking in general at a class of problems?

Comment: The word you are looking for is _logistics_.

Comment: And neither "transport scheduling" nor "logistics" are programming topics.  There are doubtless interesting programming problems in it, but to be relevant here you'd have to find one and ask it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, this is a rather vague question.

As far as programming is concerned, my impression is that logistics questions often boil down to questions about scheduling, that is, allocation of resources. Typically you face a very large number of decisions (e.g. how to direct individual trucks and loads) and want to optimize some overall number (e.g. total profit).

If the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) look like toy versions of the sort of problem you're interested in, or if [flow networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) seem relevant, then the topic you're interested in is **[discrete mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics)**.